# Find line break with Pos() in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, line-breaks

I normally work with C++Builder and just started to test in Delphi. I can't find line breaks with Delphi's (XE5) `Pos()` function and it's weird syntax. What do I wrong? With other functions like `StringReplace()` it works fine. Here is an example code:

```
sl := TStringList.Create;
sl.Add('Hello');
sl.Add('world');
sl.Add('!');

if (Pos(sl.Text, #13#10) > 0) then
    ShowMessage('1')
else if (Pos(sl.Text, #13) > 0) then
    ShowMessage('2')
else if (Pos(sl.Text, #10) > 0) then
    ShowMessage('3')
else
    ShowMessage('4');  // Comes always here...
```

That's how I always did it in C++Builder and had never a problem with it.

Comment: Even if you did pass the arguments of Pos in the right order, it's a peculiar example, since `sl.Text` will build the resulting string from an internal array of strings, using a fixed EOL delimiter.

Comment: Such an error in the transfer of the `Pos` string method to the `Pos` function (working on strings) is completely understandable, considering that in C++ `this` is the invisible implicit "first" argument on the stack. On the other hand, it is safer to follow documentation instead of intuition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing the arguments of the [`Pos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Pos) function in  a wrong order, first you must pass the  substring to search and then the buffer string.

```
function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _ShortStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
function Pos(const SubStr, Str: UnicodeString; Offset: Integer): Integer; overload;
function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _WideStr; Offset: Integer): Integer; overload;
function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _RawByteStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
```

Try this

```
if  Pos(#13#10, sl.Text) > 0 then
```

or

```
if Pos(sLineBreak, sl.Text) > 0 then
```

Comment: Oh man... thank you very much. I just feel so stupid. In C++Builder the Pos() function is a method of the string and I always get confused with the standalone functions.

Comment: @jmiller: In XE5, you can call methods on base data types now, including strings (via the `SysUtils.TStringHelper` class), eg: `uses SysUtils; if sl.Text.IndexOf(#13#10) > -1 then ...`. Note that such code is 0-based, not 1-based.